# How getting the ErrorMessage from Service in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

I don't know how I access the error message from the service. I'm using WebAPI2 and AngularJS.

Controller:

```
testApp.controller('ModalCtrl', ['$log', '$scope', '$modalInstance', '$rootScope', 'CrudService',
    function ($log, $scope, $modalInstance, $rootScope, CrudService) {
    $scope.updateItem = function (updateItem) {
       CrudService.update(updateItem)
          .success(...)
          .error(function (data) { //doesn't work: CrudService.update(...) is undefined
              $scope.dataError = data.ModelState 
          });
       $scope.ok();
    }
```

Service:

```
testApp.factory('CrudService', ['$log', 'resService',
    function ($log, resService) {
    return {
       ...
       update: function (updateItem) {
          updateItem.$update().then(function (response) {
              //SUCCESS MESSAGE definieren
          }, function (response) {
              $log.info('Update ERR:', response.data.ModelState); //Here I'm getting the error messages
              var dataError = []; 
              dataError = response.data.ModelState; //How can I use this in the Ctrl?
          });
       },
    ...
```

Resource service:

```
return {
   name: $resource(baseUrl + '/api/name/:Id', {
      Id: '@Id'
   }, {
      'update': {
         method: 'PUT'
      }
   }),
```

I want to use the variable "dataError" as $scope in the Ctrl. How can I do this?

Comment: @gr3g This doesn't work. I've tried it before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return {
   ...
   update: function (updateItem) {
      return updateItem.$update();
   },

$scope.updateItem = function (updateItem) {
   CrudService.update(updateItem).then(
      function(resp){

      },
      function(error){
        $scope.dataError = error.data.ModelState;
     }

   );
}
```

**UPDATE**

`Factory` (unlike service) isn't returning something automatically.
You need to return like that. (or return your function wich contains another return)

```
testApp.factory('CrudService', ['$log', 'resService',
    return {
       ...
       update: function (updateItem) {
          updateItem.$update().then(function (response) {
              //SUCCESS MESSAGE definieren
          }, function (response) {
              $log.info('Update ERR:', response.data.ModelState); //Here I'm getting the error messages
              var dataError = []; 
              dataError = response.data.ModelState; //How can I use this in the Ctrl?
          });
       },
    ...
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but if you want the response of your promise, you should return your promise to have it in your controller. Afther that you'll be able to handle cases and display them

Comment: This I've also tried before and it doesn't solved the problem.

Comment: How can I define this? I mean CrudService is injected in my Ctrl

Comment: Copy paste more code, I can't find the solution here

Comment: I've modified my post. I think that's all what is necessary.

Comment: Please check modification. What that the problem?

Comment: I don't know how to retrieve the variable "dataError" in my Ctrl to display the ModelState error msgs.

Comment: You wan't to display it in your html page? `{{dataError}}` in your html?

Comment: Yes but I need to send the variable dataError to the Ctrl

Comment: Can you help me in this thread? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31262068/error-save-is-not-a-function-angularjs